# What is the Mobx way to do handle set state with callbacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I am trying to convert an existing application that uses set state to use Mobx. How can i achieve the set state callback functionality using mobx. Do i need to use componentDidUpdate to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in that you need to use `componentDidUpdate` to do custom logic when the component has been re-rendered with MobX. The observable values will be synchronously updated, but the component will be re-rendered asynchronously as usual.

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ciqavojabi/edit?js,output))**

```
@observer 
class App extends Component {
  @observable value = ''

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.value = 'focus', 1000);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.ref.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        ref={ref => this.ref = ref}
        value={this.value}
        onChange={e => this.value = e.target.value}
      />
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this.

Comment: @Tholle I don't think your statement is totally correct. Even though the `clicks` observable will have the updated (synchronous) value, the DOM will not have been re-rendered yet. For instance if you had an element that was removed from the DOM due to an observable value change, that DOM element would still exist after the value has changed while in the click handler. Only until `componentDidUpdate` can you be sure that the DOM has been updated. Regarding the `setState` callback ..."guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied", meaning the DOM will reflect any changes.

Comment: @Gobot You're right. I forgot about this answer, to be honest. I should delete it. `componentDidUpdate` has to be used with MobX, as you say.